# DBT metrics.calculate error: calendar.date_all_time does not exist

Tags: dbt, dbt-metrics

I am trying to materialise a DBT metric using the following code and am getting an error.

My metric is pretty normal except I am trying to leverage the "non time based metrics" features described in this github issue : https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt_metrics/issues/97

metric:

```
select *
from {{ metrics.calculate(
    metric_list=[
        metric('median_list_price')
    ],
    grain='all_time',
    dimensions=['product_code'],
) }}
```

Error:

```
column calendar.date_all_time does not exist
```

Versions:

- dbt-core: 1.4.5
- dbt-labs/metrics: 1.4.0

I cannot find any good solutions when googling for this specific error but I came across the solution in the DBT slack channel so cross posting here.

To make the question more self contained here is the metric definition that is referenced in the metrics.calculate call

metric definition

```
version: 2

metrics:
  - name: median_list_price
    label: TODO
    model: ref('list_price_analysis')
    calculation_method: median
    expression: charge_rate
    timestamp: created_date
    time_grains: [all_time]
    dimensions:
      - product_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `grain='all_time'` and the error goes away.

As of dbt-metrics 1.4.x you can omit the time_grain when calling metrics.calculate and the default behaviour is to compute the aggregate accross the entire dataset. So the corrected call to metrics.calculate is (not grain key is removed)

```
select *
from {{ metrics.calculate(
    metric_list=[
        metric('median_list_price')
    ],
    dimensions=['product_code'],
) }}
```

Discussed here in slack (this is a public channel but you have to join the DBT slack channel) - I can remove this link if needed  https://getdbt.slack.com/archives/C046L0VTVR6/p1678904788383639